# Wordpress: delete files in server folder which are not present in Media Library

Tags: wordpress

I had a plugin with an issue and now I have around 400000 images in wp-content/upload/2022/ which are not present in Media Library.

How can I delete these files?
I am 100% sure these images are not used in my site. I mean, that if the file is not in Media Library then I can delete it.

Comment: There are plugins for this purpose.  [Read this](https://wpmudev.com/blog/daily-tip-keep-a-clean-wordpress-uploads-folder-by-deleting-unused-images/).

Comment: Backup first and then use  https://wordpress.org/plugins/media-cleaner/